# ask for version IOS in delphi

Tags: ios, delphi, pascal

The code that i use to get the version of the ios app dont work. i dont know what i am doing wrong. This is the code:

```
function GetIOSVesion : string;
{$IFDEF IOS}
 var
  AppKey: Pointer;
  AppBundle: NSBundle;
  BuildStr : NSString;
begin
  Result := '?';
  try
    AppKey := (StrToNSStr('CFBundleVersion') as ILocalObject).GetObjectID;

    AppBundle := TNSBundle.Wrap(TNSBundle.OCClass.mainBundle);
    BuildStr := TNSString.Wrap(AppBundle.infoDictionary.objectForKey(AppKey));
    Result := UTF8ToString(BuildStr.UTF8String);

  except
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

The erros i get are :
Undeclared identifier : NSBundle
Undeclared identifier : NSString
Undeclared identifier : strToNSStr
Undeclared identifier : ILocalObject

the uses for ios are:

```
    {$IFDEF APPLE}
 uses
  {$IFDEF IOS}
   iOSapi.Foundation,
  {$ELSE}
  Macapi.Foundation,
  {$ENDIF}
  Macapi.Helpers,
  Macapi.ObjectiveC;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Not a solution to your programming issue, however the `System.SysUtils` unit has `TOSVersion`, which has a property `ToString`, which gives the OS version. Use it like this: `TOSVersion.ToString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSBundle is defined in `Macapi.Foundation`. mac API is not IOS. So either you must add `Macapi.Foundation` to the uses clause or you cannot use `NSBundle` in an iOS application or it is missing from the RTL.

Comment: thank you i added this code between the unit and interface and now it works! {$IFDEF MACOS}
  {$DEFINE APPLE}
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF IOS}
  {$DEFINE APPLE}
{$ENDIF}

Comment: NSBundle *is* defined in iOSapi.Foundation